# Swiftui add a function to a custom View

Tags: ios, struct, swiftui

i'm working on a project and trying to make a custom view that i can use in an other struct with a custom function. Something like this:

```
   @State var testtext: String

   struct test1: View {
      Button(action: {//this should run a function}, label: {Text(testtext)}
   }

   struct ContentView: View {
      test1(testtext: "Test") {
         //this should be the function
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to your view just like any other argument or variable. In Swift functions are considered first-class types like an Int or String.

For example:

```
struct CustomButton: View {
    let customAction: () -> Void
 
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: customAction, label: ...)
```

```
CustomButton(customAction: { print("Button Pressed") })
```

The SwiftUI Button expects action to be of type `() -> Void` which means it takes no arguments and returns nothing. So you can only pass custom functions that match that.